# Displaying different message to logged in and logged out users

Tags: php, html, css, authentication

3rd post in 2 days lol.
I was wondering if anyone could help. I would like the below code edited so that if a customer is not logged in, the text displays "login/register" and if they are logged in, it displays "My Account"

```
<div id="myaccount">
    <a href="wordpress/my-account"><img class="bottom" src="wp-
content/themes/mt_theme/images/my_account_hover.png" alt="My 
Account"/> 
<img class="top" src="wp-content/themes/my_theme/images/my_account.png" 
alt="My Account"/>
        <p class="icotext">My Account</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#myaccount{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#myaccount img {
  position:absolute;
  left:900px;
  top: -20px;
  Height: 50px !important;
  width: 50px !important;
} 
a:hover img.top {
  opacity:0;
}
.icotext{
  position: absolute;
  left: 890px;
  top: 28px;
  color: #000000  
}
a:hover .icotext{
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 888px;
}
```

I have seen the likes of

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
```

However, I am unsure how to place the echo"" in the same place as my text currently is and add the same effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will helps

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<p class="icotext">'.'Welcome, registered user!'.'</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p class="icotext">'.'Welcome, visitor!'.'</p>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Write your code like this:

```
<div id="myaccount">
    <a href="wordpress/my-account"><img class="bottom" src="wp-
content/themes/mt_theme/images/my_account_hover.png" alt="My 
Account"/> 
<img class="top" src="wp-content/themes/my_theme/images/my_account.png" 
alt="My Account"/>
        <p class="icotext">
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
       </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Or you could write a code like this:

```
<p class="icotext"><?php echo (is_user_logged_in()?'Your online':'Hi visitor') ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP guru, but you would put the code inline, in the markup itself. Something like the code block below, this way you can conditionally show what you want.

```
<?php if(conditions): ?>
... HTML CODE ...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if the user is logged in or not earlier in your code, and then insert the correct text later on.  For example:

```
<?php
$loginText = "";
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $loginText = "My Account";
} else {
    $loginText = "Login/Register";
}
?>

<div id="myaccount">
    <a href="wordpress/my-account"><img class="bottom" src="wp-
content/themes/mt_theme/images/my_account_hover.png" alt="My 
Account"/> 
<img class="top" src="wp-content/themes/my_theme/images/my_account.png" 
alt="My Account"/>
        <p class="icotext"><?= $loginText ?></p>
    </a>
</div>
```

The `<?= ?>` syntax lets you insert a variable where you want.

Comment: I am not at my computer at the minute but when I get home from work I will be giving this a try, can definitely see the logic in this option. fingers crossed :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myaccount">
    <a href="wordpress/my-account"><img class="bottom" src="wp-
content/themes/mt_theme/images/my_account_hover.png" alt="My 
Account"/> 
<img class="top" src="wp-content/themes/my_theme/images/my_account.png" 
alt="My Account"/>
        <p class="icotext">
        <?php
          if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            echo 'login/register';
          } else {
            echo 'My Account';
          }
        ?>
        </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the condition the user is logged in or not. To do this you can either

> Set the Session as login and check Session_Login as boolean

Now comes the part of checking it run

```
    if($SESSION_LOGIN){
        echo "<p class = "icotext">"."Welcome , registered user"."</p>";
    }else{
        echo "<p class = "icotext">"."Welcome ,visitor"."</p>";
    }
```

Make sure to start the session first.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a block of code inside your html file which returns the current message based on the current state of user (logged in/out). Well, it's not the best way to solve this "problem", but that's the wordpress' way. Let's take an example:

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_SESSION['user_token'])){
?>

 <div id="myaccount">
 <a href="wordpress/my-account"><img class="bottom" src="wp-
    content/themes/mt_theme/images/my_account_hover.png" alt="My 
      Account"/> 
 <img class="top" src="wp-content/themes/my_theme/images/my_account.png" 
 alt="My Account"/>
    <p class="icotext">My Account</p>
 </a>
</div>

<?php } else { echo "Logged out user message here"; } ?>
```

That's the best approach in your case, given that you are using wordpress.